# Replace text each span of a piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a variable with a table:

```
var tableCode='<table><tr><td><span class'thisone'>'the_text_to_change'</span><span class'thisone'>'other_text_to_change'</span><span class'thisone'>'another_text_to_change'</span></td></tr></table>'
```

I would want to replace the text inside each span with the class 'thisone', each one depending on the value inside of the class.

So the variable tableCode should be:

```
var tableCode='<table><tr><td><span class'thisone'>'the_text_changed_1'</span><span class'thisone'>'the_text_changed_2'</span><span class'thisone'>'the_text_changed_3'</span></td></tr></table>'
```

I have been reading the documentation of each: https://api.jquery.com/each/, but it is for the DOM and not for a variable in Javascript.

So: Read the variable, go throw it and detect the spans with a specific css class and change the value depending on the text.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: 1) Your code is wrong (cfr the colors, if you use single quotes everywhere it can't work unless you escape it) 2) Try to actually write some code 3) Come back her if you're stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Wzn88/)</kbd>

```
var tableCode = "<table><tr><td><span class='thisone'>'the_text_to_change'</span><span class='thisone'>'other_text_to_change'</span><span class='thisone'>'another_text_to_change'</span></td></tr></table>";
tableCode = $(tableCode); //make it a jQuery Object
tableCode.find('span.thisone').text(function (i) {
    return 'the_text_to_change_' + ++i;
}); //find span with class thisone and set text
console.log(tableCode.html()); //to retrieve the changed string use tableCode.html()
```

Comment: This code is not replacing the text inside the spans

Comment: @Za7pi change your table structure too as in fiddle .

Comment: It is working, but one thing, if you put the variable like this(adding two tr):
`var tableCode = "<tr><td><span class='thisone'>the_text_to_change</span></td></tr><tr></td><span class='thisone'>other_text_to_change</span><span class='thisone'>another_text_to_change</span></td></tr>";` 
It is not working, it is changing only the first span. Thanks!!

Comment: @Za7pi you markup was wrong  --> here `</tr><tr></td><span` you have invalid  `</td>`  tag change it to `var tableCode = "<tr><td><span class='thisone'>the_text_to_change</span></td></tr><tr><td><span class='thisone'>other_text_to_change</span><span class='thisone'>another_text_to_change</span></td></tr>";` --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Wzn88/6/

Comment: Yes, sorry. I hav changed it and, yes your code does it well, but when you do:
`console.log(tableCode.html());` It is only printing one spam

Comment: @Za7pi Yeah when you get html it only get's the 1st `tr` element html. To get all `td` tags use .each() loop -->http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Wzn88/7/

Comment: Ok, now i am getting the td, is there any possibility to get also the tr? I mean: is there any posibility to get the same string that i had before, but with the text of the span changed.

Comment: @Za7pi yes `var x = $.trim(tableCode.parent().html().toString());
console.log(x);` --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Wzn88/8/

Comment: This is printing in the console all the html code of the page

Comment: Sorry, it is telling me that it is null:TypeError: tableCode.parent(...).html(...) is null

Comment: @Za7pi Use `var div = $('<div/>', {
    html: tableCode
}).html();
console.log(div);`  -->  http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Wzn88/9/

Comment: It´s working, but if I put only `var tableCode = "<span class='thisone'>the_text_to_change</span>";`
It is not working.

Comment: @Za7pi  See --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Wzn88/11/ for different scenario there is different code start learning .

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var jqueryObj=$("<table><tr><td><span class='thisone'>'the_text_to_change'</span><span class='thisone'>'other_text_to_change'</span><span class='thisone'>'another_text_to_change'</span></td></tr></table>");
jqueryObj.find('span').each(function(){
$(this).text($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/SsCvu/)</kbd>

Comment: This code is only filtering by span and not by class name

Comment: This is working:

`var jqueryObj=$("<table><tr><td><span class='thisone'>'the_text_to_change'</span><span class='thisone'>'other_text_to_change'</span><span class='thisone'>'another_text_to_change'</span></td></tr></table>");
jqueryObj.find('span.thisone').each(function(){
$(this).text('someText');
});`
But if i put the variable like this:
`var jqueryObj=$("<tr><td><span class='thisone'>'the_text_to_change'</span><span class='thisone'>'other_text_to_change'</span><span class='thisone'>'another_text_to_change'</span></td></tr>");`
Without table tag, it is only changing the first span. Why?